# symfony runtime exception on query with inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

I have a strange problem and I need help.

I work on a symfony project with a mate.

And when an user login this app, after checking his login/password on the Active Directory, if it's the first connection to the app, the user bundle will insert the user information get in the AD in the database.

One of this information is the team of this user, this information is a table with inheritance.

Every time the app query the database for checking if the team already exist or just insert the user in the database, i got an exception.

> Runtime Notice: Declaration of Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\JoinedSubclassPersister::getLockTablesSql() should be compatible with Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister::getLockTablesSql()

The weirdest thing is that the function work perfectly fine on the computer of my mate.

Doctrine schema ok, other query on database ok, same configuration.

I've got no idea where is the problem.

Thanks by advance for the help

Comment: Compare your php version and php.ini with your mate. Maybe you are using older version of php.

Comment: same php version and i took his php.ini same problem

Comment: Did you both do `composer install` instead of `composer update`? You should have the same versions for every vendor that you include. Try delete all `vendors/*` and run `composer install` on both machines. If the problem will occur on your mate's machine then you will need to find wrong version for one of vendor's libs.

Comment: Well deleting all vendor/* and run the composer install solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael Sivolobov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting vendor/* and run the composer install solve the problem